# What does the value from dereferencing a function pointer means

Tags: c++, function-pointers

```
#include <iostream>

void PrintTheValue(int(*func)(int a));

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    PrintTheValue([](int a) {return a; });
    
    return 0;
}

void PrintTheValue(int(*func)(int a)) {
    std::cout << *func << std::endl;
}
```

In my concept of understanding the `func`, it would be a pointer to an int passed by value. But in this case I'm passing a lambda which doesn't seem to be called anywhere. (So there isn't any value at all?)

When I run this, it doesn't break the program, but instead printed `00EE6F80`.

What does this address mean? I have no idea how to interpret it.

Comment: What's the compiler? I got the result `1` with [gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2BrgDY2KukDINOfp).

Comment: Visual Studio 2017

Comment: *'it would be a pointer to an int passed by value'* – no, it is a pointer to a function, i. e. it contains the address in memory of that function - or in this case the lambda, which decays to ordinary function as closure is empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In my concept of understanding the `func`, it would be a pointer to an int passed by value.

`func` is a pointer to function, which takes an `int` and returns `int`.

> But in this case I'm passing a lambda which doesn't seem to be called anywhere.

You're passing a lambda without capturing, which could convert to pointer to function implicitly. In `PrintTheValue`, `*func`, i.e dereference on the pointer results in a reference to function, and for being passed to [`operator<<` of `std::cout`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt), it converts to function pointer again, then converts to `bool` with value `true` (as a non-null pointer), then you should get the result `1` (or `true` with the usage of `std::boolalpha`). If you want to call on `func` you could `func(42)` (or `(*func)(42)`).

Comment: Hm, maybe MSVC treats the function pointer like ordinary pointer and prints the address instead. Is this usage of function pointers defined behaviour at all?

Comment: Does that mean in ```PrintTheValue``` one should not interpret the ```func``` as an pointer to int, but a pointer to a reference to a function ( i.e. a pointer to a reference to an int )?

Comment: @Aconcagua If that's the case the code doesn't look like it has created any value at all.  I haven't read anything about lambda allocating space for a variable or something it doesn't make much sense to me

Comment: @IKnowHowBitcoinWorks `func` is a pointer to function, you can call on it like `func(42)`. Note that pointer to function and pointer to object (like `int*`, `char*`) are two different things.

Comment: Well, so undefined behaviour. So whatever the compilers do, the behaviour is correct according to the standard. GCC apparently has decided to treat function pointers – re-converted or not – as booleans, while MSVC in contrast opted for `void*`. In any case, as undefined behaviour is involved, your programme is invalid in any case.

Comment: @Aconcagua I think it's not UB, i.e. MSVC is wrong. Function pointer can't be converted to `void*`, then it should be printed out as `bool` at last.

Comment: @songyuanyao I'm not aware of the standard mandating such behaviour. Any references to it?

Comment: @Aconcagua You mean the conversion from function pointer to `void*` part?

Comment: @songyuanyao More general: What does the standard mandate to handle a function pointer in such situation? `void*` was rather intended as example/analogy – to *whatever* MSVC converts to, it seems to print the address of the function – there might even be an overload for function pointers. But what does the standard tell about?

Comment: @Aconcagua The standard doesn't tell specially; according to the rule of [implicit conversion](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/conv.ptr#2), only pointer to object could convert to *pointer to cv void*, and there's no overloading taking `int(*)(int)` for `operator<<`([here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/ostream.inserters.arithmetic) and [here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/ostream.inserters)). But function pointer could convert to `bool`, and there's an overloading taking `bool` (according to the standard above), which should be the valid result for printing a function pointer.

Answer (score 3):

A lambda is an unnamed **function object** of the *closure type*.
The crucial part for this case, this class **does not overload the `operator<<`.**

When you dereference the passed lambda in `*func`, there is no overload for `operator<<`, so it converts to nearest acceptable result which is `bool` *(at first it reverts to a regular pointer)*.

The [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer):

> Dereferencing a function pointer yields the lvalue identifying the pointed-to function

```
int f();
int (*p)() = f;  // pointer p is pointing to f
(*p)();          // function f invoked through the function lvalue
// But no sense in *p
```

It should print `1` *(since non-null pointer)*, which it does for me *(g++)*. The language does allow us to do so, but there's **no sense in dereferencing a pointer to function without calling the function**. All the peculiarities of the function pointers are due to that they have one reasonable usage, so anything you do with them will support that usage - [@Pete Becker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1593860/pete-becker)

For more on Function Pointers check [here](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/function-pointers/), it will aid.

Comment: Dereferencing a pointer-to-function yields (gasp) a pointer-to-function. `p()`, `(p)()`, `(*p)()`, `(**p)()`, `(***p)()`, etc. all mean exactly the same thing. Similarly, the name of a function decays into a pointer to that function, and taking the address of that pointer-to-function gives you a pointer to that function. So `f`, `&f`, `&&f`, `&&&f`, etc. all mean exactly the same thing. Pointers to functions are somewhat peculiar, mostly because they only have one reasonable usage, so anything you do with them will support that usage. +1.